# How to use Find to locate files where -mtime is older than -ctime

Tags: linux, find

I need to find files on a CentOS server that have a Modify date older than Change date. I need this because I have files which have spoofed modified dates.

Like:

```
[root@server /home/accountname/public_html]# stat index.php
  File: `index.php'
  Size: 638             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: f001h/60001d    Inode: 2400001     Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (  NNN/accountname)   Gid: (  NNN/accountname)
Access: 2017-08-23 18:42:23.325705099 -0700
Modify: 2015-07-06 18:41:56.000000000 -0700
Change: 2017-08-21 18:41:56.204893561 -0700
```

I used this to find files modified in last 30 days, but a file like the above wouldn't show up unless I do a ctime.

```
find /home/accountname/public_html/ -type f -mtime -30 >> /somepath/filesinlast30days.txt
```

It would be nice to be able to do something like:

```
find . -type f -mtime < -ctime >> pathtofile
```

**-mtime < -ctime** (-mtime "older than" -ctime)

Maybe there's a better tool? I'm posting this while still searching as I'm pressed for time and initial search didn't produce help.